# Aggregation Field Missing in output of ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie in learning aggregations in elastic search
Below is my query in kibana

```
    GET /vehicles/cars/_search

{
  "aggs": {
    "popular_cars": {
      "terms": {"field": "make.keyword","size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_price": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }

        }
      }
```

My output from elastic search

```
    {
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 16,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [Here it contains the long list of hits]
  }
}
   }
```

My confusion is i am not getting aggregation field displayed in the output am i missing something here?

Comment: Is there a real empty line between  GET /vehicles/cars/_search and you query (in the dev tools) ? If so try to remove it

Comment: Agreed with @PierreMallet, remove the empty line and properly format your code

Comment: @PierreMallet Yes there was an empty line between URL and the query , thanks i am getting it now ,thx